# Why does Google Computer Engine bind my program to IPv6 ports?

Tags: networking, docker, google-cloud-platform, ipv6, google-compute-engine

I am writing a server that binds to a number of local ports (including `80` and `443`). Whenever I run it on Google Computer Engine (GCE), using their Container-Optimized OS (COS) and a Docker container, the ports bind to IPv6, and not IPv4.

```sh
$ netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36265         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 10.128.0.33:68          0.0.0.0:*
```

This is an important distinction, because there is logic in my program that tries to connect directly to the local interface using the IPv4 address of `127.0.0.1`.

How can I specify for my GCE instance to use an IPv4 port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit

**One important thing to note( as pointed out in the comments)** - while it may be binding to an interface using both IPv4 and IPv6, IPv6 routing will not work on Google Cloud (not yet supported internally).

---

So, it turns out that this is a confusing "feature" with how Docker does networking, and it should still allow IPv4 connections as well as IPv6.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006034/1720774) for more details. I've quoted the answer below for posterity's sake:

> ... [github.com/docker/docker/issues/2174](http://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2174) is about showing binding only to IPv6 in `netstat`, but that is not an issue. As that github issues states:
>
> > When setting up the proxy, Docker requests the loopback address '127.0.0.1', Linux realises this is an address that exists in IPv6 (as ::0) and opens on both (but it is formally an IPv6 socket). When you run netstat it sees this and tells you it is an IPv6 - but it is still listening on IPv4. If you have played with your settings a little, you may have disabled this trick Linux does - by setting net.ipv6.bindv6only = 1.
>
> In other words, just because you see it as IPv6 only, it is still able to communicate on IPv4 unless you have IPv6 set to only bind on IPv6 with the net.ipv6.bindv6only setting. To be clear,  net.ipv6.bindv6only should be 0 - you can run `sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only` to verify.

Comment: Actually, you are misunderstanding the Linux OS and the documentation that you are quoting. Your version of Linux is providing both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols (IP Stacks). You have an application inside your container (Apache, Nginx, etc) that detects IPv6 and binds to all IPv6 capable network interfaces. Google Cloud Platform does not support IPv6 for Compute Engine. The loopback address for IPv6 is not even being used in your listing. IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols. Unless you have a mapper running (which you don't) one does not impact or affect the other.

Comment: @JohnHanley You're right, the IPv6 loopback interface is not being used, however the software is being bound to all interfaces on IPv6 (see `tcp6` in the netstat output). I am aware that Google Cloud does not support IPv6 for Compute Engine, which had confused me even more.

I had written my program in Go myself, which acts as the server instead of something like nginx, so it's the one looking to bind to a port. However, even when I specify binding to `0.0.0.0:443` (which is an IPv4 address), it still binds to `:::443` over `tcp6`, which leads me to believe it's either Docker or GCE.

Comment: Internal to your VM or Container, the OS does not know that the next hop does not support IPv6. The OS is configured for IPv6, that is all that matters to the applications binding to IP. The fact that IPv6 packets will be dropped when they arrive at the Google networking layer does not matter yet. This will result in connection errors once something tries to use IPv6.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. So it binds to the interface, listening for both IPv4 and IPv6, but it won't actually work when using IPv6, correct?

Comment: Correct. There are exceptions when IPv6->IPv4 mappers are setup. Note I am commenting on communications to devices external the machine/vm/os. Inside the OS, IPv6 on localhost will work.

Comment: @JohnHanley Right, that's what I thought. Okay, thanks a lot for the clarification. I'll update my answer with some more details to reflect that.